# Cannot GET by ID from a db using nodejs,mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

im trying to build a RESTful api for storing users with passwords and emails and Products with Comments and replies.At this moment i'm trying to fetch some data from a db with the name Products, and i want to display a product information given his ID but i recieve a:

**cannot GET /api/productinfo/:56990ef287f61aa20fdf5288**

here is the server.js

```
    var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var morgan      = require('morgan');
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var passport    = require('passport');
var config      = require('./config/database'); // get db config file
var User        = require('./app/models/user'); // get the mongoose model
var Products      = require('./app/models/products'); //get the mongoose model
var Makeissue     = require('./app/models/makeissue'); //get the mongoose model
var port        = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var jwt         = require('jwt-simple');

// get our request parameters
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// log to console
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// Use the passport package in our application
app.use(passport.initialize());

// demo Route (GET http://localhost:8080)
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('The API is at http://localhost:' + port + '/api');
});

// connect to database
mongoose.connect(config.database);

// pass passport for configuration
require('./config/passport')(passport);

// bundle our routes
var apiRoutes = express.Router();


// create a new user account (POST http://localhost:8080/api/signup)
apiRoutes.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.name || !req.body.password || !req.body.email) {
    res.json({success: false, msg: 'Please pass name and password and email.'});
  } else {
    var newUser = new User({
      name: req.body.name,
      password: req.body.password,
      email: req.body.email
    });
    // save the user
    newUser.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Username already exists.'});
      }
      res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful created new user.'});
    });
  }
});

// route to authenticate a user (POST http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate)
apiRoutes.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({
    name: req.body.name
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (!user) {
      res.send({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'});
    } else {
      // check if password matches
      user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (isMatch && !err) {
          // if user is found and password is right create a token
          var token = jwt.encode(user, config.secret);
          // return the information including token as JSON
          res.json({success: true, token: 'JWT ' + token});
        } else {
          res.send({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.'});
        }
      });
    }
  });
});


// create a new Product (POST http://localhost:8080/api/productsignup)
apiRoutes.post('/resources/productsignup', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.name || !req.body.serialnumber) {
    res.json({success: false, msg: 'Please pass name and serial number.'});
    } else {
    var newProducts = new Products({
      name: req.body.name,
      serialnumber: req.body.serialnumber     
    });
    // save the Product
    newProducts.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Product already exists.'});
      }
      res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful created new Product.'});
    });
  }
});

apiRoutes.post('/resources/createpost', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.issue) {
    res.json({success: false, msg: 'Please pass a issue.'});
    } else {
    var newMakeissue = new Makeissue({
      issue: req.body.issue    
    });
    // save the Product
    newMakeissue.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Post already exists.'});
      }
      res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful created new post.'});
    });
  }
});





 apiRoutes.get('/resources/productinfo/:name' , function(req, res) {
  if (!req.param('name')) res.status(400).send("Please send a proper name");
  else{
      access.findProductsByName(Products, req.param('name'), function(Products) {
        if (!text) res.status(500).send("server error");
      });
    }
  });



// route to a restricted info (GET http://localhost:8080/api/memberinfo)
apiRoutes.get('/memberinfo', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}), function(req, res) {
  var token = getToken(req.headers);
  if (token) {
    var decoded = jwt.decode(token, config.secret);
    User.findOne({
      name: decoded.name
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!user) {
          return res.status(403).send({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'});
        } else {
          res.json({success: true, msg: 'Welcome in the member area ' + user.name + '!'});
        }
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(403).send({success: false, msg: 'No token provided.'});
  }
});

getToken = function (headers) {
  if (headers && headers.authorization) {
    var parted = headers.authorization.split(' ');
    if (parted.length === 2) {
      return parted[1];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};


// connect the api routes under /api/*
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
module.exports = apiRoutes;


// Start the server
app.listen(port);
console.log('http://localhost:' + port);
```

and the database.js

```
module.exports = {
  'secret': 'di.ionio.gr',
  'database': 'mongodb://localhost/firstapp'
};
```

and the package.json

```
{
  "name": "firstapp",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^0.8.5",
    "body-parser": "~1.9.2",
    "express": "~4.9.8",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.3.1",
    "mongoose": "~4.2.4",
    "mongodb" : "~1.2.5",
    "morgan": "~1.5.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I might be terribly wrong, but your url should be `GET /api/resources/productinfo/56990ef287f61aa20fdf5288`

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but shouldn't your app.get request use `_id` as, if I'm not mistaking, you're trying to get an item in mongo based on it's generated ID, and not a custom one?

Comment: yes thats true! the mongo generates an ID, i dont have a custom ID, i take te generated id and i put it in url but i recieve a error

Comment: So modifying this line :`res.send({id:req.params.id});` when you want to get a product, to `res.send({_id:req.params.id});` does nothing? I've just recently started using mongo, so I'm learning as well

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that there is no such route `'/api/productinfo/:name'` defined.

According to your code, you define the `apiRoutes` middleware for the route `'/api'`. This means that any routes you define on `apiRoutes` will begin with `'/api'`. For example, you can make 'GET' requests to `'/api/memberinfo'`.

The `'/resources/productinfo/:name'` routes is defined on the `apiRoutes` middleware which means your requests should go to `'api/resources/productinfo/:name'`. Hence, your request should be changed to:

```
/api/resources/productinfo/56990ef287f61aa20fdf5288
```

Comment: yeap thats true! although the result not coming! the db stuck on loading to fetch the data! something is going wrong with the db!